# How to handle react set state using dictionary syntax with uglify?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, uglifyjs2

React's documentation has handle change function which retrieves object key at the run time.

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs

I have similar;

```
//handles state change
handleChange = prop => event => {
    this.setState({[prop]: event.target.value})
}
```

As far as I understand uglify plugin is changing key names at build time so how can/should I handle this?

Example:
Let's say we have `handleChange('name')`, but in build time `state.name` becomes lets say `state.n` but It's updating `state.name` not `state.n`

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean? have you tried it and it didn't work? if it will change a key name in one place it will change it on all other places that this variable name exists

Comment: With computed property names, it's not the name of the variable that matters (i.e. `prop`), but its value (what value does `prop` hold?). Your example should work fine as-is.

Comment: It looks like not working as expected. I've added example case.

Comment: IIRC uglify won't touch strings, so if you're passing string literals to `handleChange` (as you have in your example) then it's not actually a dynamic value, and won't be minified.  I vaguely recall this was how Angular 1 got around avoiding minification of meaningfully named variables.